# Unable to work in second tab using java selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, arraylist, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am registering on a website and for OTP and signup link I am using yopmail so I have to toggle between two tabs everything is working fine but when I switch to second window using any browser webdriver is not focussing on the second tab and giving error as array index out of bounds I have triedit on both chrome and firefox browsers but still getting the same error

```
package Stripetesting;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Plansinfirefox {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/gt51022/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.32.0-linux64/geckodriver");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String windowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        driver.get("https://app.ai/");
        driver.navigate().forward();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().forward();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"formBasicEmail\"]")).sendKeys("wond@yopmail.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Qwerty@1");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.navigate().forward();
        driver.findElement(By.className("checkmark")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/form/button")).click();
        driver.navigate().forward();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        // Selecting the team from here //
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div")).click();
        driver.navigate().forward();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        // Clicking on add new team member //
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        ArrayList<String> tabs3 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
        // Generating random email //
        driver.get("http://www.yopmail.com");
        // Clicking on random email generator //
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/main/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/a[1]/div[2]/h3")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        // Clicking on copy to clipboard //
        WebElement copytoclipboard  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class=\"notmobile\"])[2]"));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.click(copytoclipboard).doubleClick().perform();
        // navigating to main window //
        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"formPlaintextEmail\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL,"v");
        // Selecting the role from here //
        driver.navigate().forward();driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/input[1]")).click();
       driver.navigate().forward();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        // Selecting the permissions from here //
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id=\"basic-typeahead-multiple-item-16\"]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span)[22]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id=\"teams\"]")).click();
        driver.navigate().forward();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/span[1]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.navigate().forward();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class=\"btn btn-primary\"]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        // If you want to sign out //
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class=\"rounded-circle\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href=\"#\"]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        // Opening new browser so commenting this code //
        //driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.WINDOW);
        // User has received invitation //
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/gt51022/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.yopmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL,"v"); //replace the test email
        //driver.get("http://www.yopmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[4]/button/i\n")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.switchTo().frame("ifmail");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("http://app.ambaram.ai/signup")).click();
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs3.get(2));
        driver.switchTo().activeElement();
        driver.navigate().forward();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.className("form-control")).sendKeys("buyer");
        driver.navigate().forward();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/form/div[2]/input")).sendKeys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL,"v");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.className("checkmark")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/form/button")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/p/a")).click();
        driver.navigate().forward();
        /*Thread.sleep(4000);
        // Commenting this code for usage checking //
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"fullName\"]")).sendKeys("Bestfit");
        driver.navigate().forward();
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("Second@yopmail.com");
        driver.navigate().forward();
        driver.findElement(By.className("checkmark")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/form/button")).click();
        //perform other operations.
        // Stopping the robot class as we have tab already opened //
        /*Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);*/
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs3.get(1));
        //driver.get("http://www.yopmail.com");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login\"]")).sendKeys("nu"); //replace the test email
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[4]/button/i\n")).click();
        driver.switchTo().frame("ifmail");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        String strCode = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mail\"]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/span")).getText(); //replace the locator for verification code
        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println(strCode);
        System.out.println("----------------");
        //Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL, "c")).build().perform();
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs3.get(2));
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.navigate().forward();
        driver.findElement(By.id("code1")).sendKeys(strCode);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            driver.navigate().forward();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class=\"otp btn btn-primary\"]")).click();
            driver.navigate().forward();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name=\"newPassword\"]")).sendKeys("Qwert@1");
            driver.navigate().forward();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name=\"comfirmNewPass\"] ")).sendKeys("Qwert@1");
            driver.navigate().forward();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class=\"otp btn btn-primary\"]")).click();
            driver.navigate().forward();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL,"v");
            driver.navigate().forward();
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Qwert@1");
            driver.navigate().forward();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class=\"checkmark\"]")).click();
            driver.navigate().forward();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class=\"btn btn-primary\"]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class=\"toggleHide\"])[2]")).click();
            // User click on joining a team //
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div/button")).click();
            //New Team Creation //
            /*driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class=\"toggleHide\"])[2]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class=\"NewUserWrap secondaryBtn\"]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.name("teamLogo")).sendKeys("/home/gt51022/Downloads/Wallpapers/Good.jpg");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.name("name")).sendKeys("Creaters");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@name=\"description\"]")).sendKeys("Of good time");
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/form/div[3]/button[2]")).click();*/
            // Changing the profile photo here //
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class=\"rounded-circle\"]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/header/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/a[1]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            WebElement elementLocator = driver.findElement(By.name("profilePicture"));
            actions.click(driver.findElement(By.name("profilePicture")));
            //actions.moveToElement(elementLocator).click().perform();
            driver.findElement(By.name("profilePicture")).sendKeys("/home/gt51022/Downloads/ca-times.brightspotcdn.jpeg");
            //driver.findElement(By.name("profilePicture")).sendKeys("/home/gt8201/Downloads/Kolkata.jpeg");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class=\"activateBtn btn btn-primary\"]")).click();
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            actions.click(driver.findElement(By.name("profilePicture")));
        }
        // Navigating back to the dashboard //
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class=\"toggleHide\"]")).click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two Methods, and then you can use `tabnumber` for switching tabs

```
public void switchTab(int tabNumber){

    driver.switchTo().window(listTabs().get(tabNumber));
}

public List<String> listTabs(){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String window: driver.getWindowHandles()){
        list.add(window);
    }
    return list;
}
```